# how to sign a message with ecdsa privatekey using golang?

Tags: python, go, cryptography, ecdsa, cosmos-blockchain

I am trying to sign a message in `go` generated via hd wallet's private key using cosmos sdk. Below is the equivalent implementation in python which generates the signed message / signature as expected when submitted/verified is working properly but unable to get it working wtih `Go` implementation. Any inputs for equivalent golang version of the python implementation is much appreciated. Thank you.

Python version uses sha256 , ecdsa but when using the equivalent cyrpto/ecdsa doesn't return valid signature.

> Python

```
    def test_sign_message(self):
        """ Tests the ability of the signer to sing message """
      
        # Loading up the signer object to use for the operation
        signer: TestSigners = TestSigners.from_mnemonic("blast about old claw current first paste risk involve victory edit current")
        sample_payload_to_sign = "75628d14409a5126e6c882d05422c06f5eccaa192c082a9a5695a8e707109842'
        # print("test".encode("UTF-8").hex())
        s = signer.sign(sample_payload_to_sign)
        print(s)


from typing import List, Tuple, Dict, Union, Any
from hdwallet.hdwallet import HDWallet
from ecdsa.util import sigencode_der
from ecdsa.curves import SECP256k1
from ecdsa.keys import SigningKey
import mnemonic
import hashlib
import ecdsa


class TestSigners():

    HD_WALLET_PARAMS: Dict[str, Tuple[int, bool]] = {
        "purpose": (44, True),
        "coinType": (1022, True),
        "account": (0, True),
        "change": (0, False),
    }

    def __init__(
            self,
            seed: Union[bytes, bytearray, str]
    ) -> None:
        """ Instantiates a new signer object from the seed phrase

        Args:
            seed (Union[bytes, bytearray, str]): The seed phrase used to generate the public and
                private keys.
        """

        self.seed: Union[bytes, bytearray] = seed if isinstance(seed, (bytes, bytearray)) else bytearray.fromhex(seed)

    @classmethod
    def from_mnemonic(
            cls,
            mnemonic_phrase: Union[str, List[str], Tuple[str]]
    ) -> 'Signer':
        """
        Instantiates a new Signer object from the mnemonic phrase passed.

        Args:
            mnemonic_phrase (Union[str, :obj:`list` of :obj:`str`, :obj:`tuple` of :obj:`str`):
                A string, list, or a tuple of the mnemonic phrase. If the argument is passed as an
                iterable, then it will be joined with a space.

        Returns:
            Signer: A new signer initalized through the mnemonic phrase.
        """

        # If the supplied mnemonic phrase is a list then convert it to a string
        if isinstance(mnemonic_phrase, (list, tuple)):
            mnemonic_string: str = " ".join(mnemonic_phrase)
        else:
            mnemonic_string: str = mnemonic_phrase

        mnemonic_string: str = " ".join(mnemonic_phrase) if isinstance(mnemonic_phrase,
                                                                       (list, tuple)) else mnemonic_phrase

        return cls(mnemonic.Mnemonic.to_seed(mnemonic_string))

    def public_key(
            self,
            index: int = 0
    ) -> str:
        """
        Gets the public key for the signer for the specified account index

        Args:
            index (int): The account index to get the public keys for.

        Returns:
            str: A string of the public key for the wallet
        """

        return str(self.hdwallet(index).public_key())

    def private_key(
            self,
            index: int = 0
    ) -> str:
        """
        Gets the private key for the signer for the specified account index

        Args:
            index (int): The account index to get the private keys for.

        Returns:
            str: A string of the private key for the wallet
        """

        return str(self.hdwallet(index).private_key())

    def hdwallet(
            self,
            index: int = 0
    ) -> HDWallet:
        """
        Creates an HDWallet object suitable for the Radix blockchain with the passed account index.

        Args:
            index (int): The account index to create the HDWallet object for.

        Returns:
            HDWallet: An HD wallet object created with the Radix Parameters for a given account
                index.
        """

        hdwallet: HDWallet = HDWallet()
        hdwallet.from_seed(seed=self.seed.hex())
        for _, values_tuple in self.HD_WALLET_PARAMS.items():
            value, hardened = values_tuple
            hdwallet.from_index(value, hardened=hardened)
        hdwallet.from_index(index, True)

        return hdwallet

    def sign(
            self,
            data: str,
            index: int = 0
    ) -> str:
        """
        Signs the given data using the private keys for the account at the specified account index.

        Arguments:
            data (str): A string of the data which we wish to sign.
            index (int): The account index to get the private keys for.

        Returns:
            str: A string of the signed data
        """

        signing_key: SigningKey = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(  # type: ignore
            string=bytearray.fromhex(self.private_key(index)),
            curve=SECP256k1,
            hashfunc=hashlib.sha256
        )

        return signing_key.sign_digest(  # type: ignore
            digest=bytearray.fromhex(data),
            sigencode=sigencode_der
        ).hex()
```

> GO ( Not Working )

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/crypto/hd"
    "github.com/cosmos/go-bip39"
    "github.com/decred/dcrd/bech32"
    "github.com/tendermint/tendermint/crypto/secp256k1"
)

func main() {

   seed := bip39.NewSeed("blast about old claw current first paste risk involve victory edit current", "")
    fmt.Println("Seed: ", hex.EncodeToString(seed)) // Seed:  dd5ffa7088c0fa4c665085bca7096a61e42ba92e7243a8ad7fbc6975a4aeea1845c6b668ebacd024fd2ca215c6cd510be7a9815528016af3a5e6f47d1cca30dd

    master, ch := hd.ComputeMastersFromSeed(seed)
    path := "m/44'/1022'/0'/0/0'"
    priv, err := hd.DerivePrivateKeyForPath(master, ch, path)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Derivation Path: ", path)                 // Derivation Path:  m/44'/118'/0'/0/0'
    fmt.Println("Private Key: ", hex.EncodeToString(priv)) // Private Key:  69668f2378b43009b16b5c6eb5e405d9224ca2a326a65a17919e567105fa4e5a

    var privKey = secp256k1.PrivKey(priv)
    pubKey := privKey.PubKey()
    fmt.Println("Public Key: ", hex.EncodeToString(pubKey.Bytes())) // Public Key:  03de79435cbc8a799efc24cdce7d3b180fb014d5f19949fb8d61de3f21b9f6c1f8

    //str := "test"
    str := "75628d14409a5126e6c882d05422c06f5eccaa192c082a9a5695a8e707109842"
    //hx := hex.EncodeToString([]byte(str))
    //fmt.Println(hx)
    sign, err := privKey.Sign([]byte(str))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(sign))
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from the post what `data = b'test'` represents. Since `sign_digest()` does _not_ hash the data, `data = b'test'` could mean the data _itself_, or the (SHA256) _hash_ of the data. Which is true here (usually the hash of the data is signed)? If `data = b'test'` represents the hash of the data, is the data itself known in addition to the hash, so that the data is available in the Go function?

Comment: The problem is with go's implementation of sign for the same message with same private key ( python vs go's crypto.PrivKey) gives different signature lengths and when submitted to the network returns invalid signature. Essentially am trying to transform python version to golang & couldn't get it working with go ecdsa.

Comment: Both codes are mainly incompatible for two reasons: (1) the Python code uses the ASN.1/DER format for the signature, while the Go code uses IEEE P1363. (2) The Python code does not hash the passed data, while the Go code does.

Comment: To fix (2), it must be known whether the message itself or the message hash is passed to `signer.sign()` in the Python code. Currently, it looks like the message _itself_ is passed, so the _unhashed_ message is signed. This is contradicted by the fact that usually the _hashed_ message is signed. Also the hex encoding could be an indication that rather the message hash is passed. But only you can clarify this.

Comment: You are right , I intend to "test" as simple message for demonstration but originally payloadToSign is sha256(sha256(unsigned_tx_bytes)) in case of python. I am passing the same hashed message to the go version. Eg: hashed payload to sign "75628d14409a5126e6c882d05422c06f5eccaa192c082a9a5695a8e707109842"

Comment: For the porting it is important to know whether only `sha256(sha256(unsigned_tx_bytes))` is available in the Go code or also `unsigned_tx_bytes`, so that the latter can be used. Also, just to be on the safe side, is the _double_ hashing with SHA256 correct or a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both codes return hex encoded as private key

```
33f34dad4bc0ce9dc320863509aed43cab33a93a29752779ae0df6dbbea33e56
```

and as compressed public key

```
026557fe37d5cab1cc8edf474f4baff67dbb2305f1764e42d31b09f83296f5de2b
```

Since both codes provide the same keys, the issue must be with signing!

---

As test message for signing the UTF8 encoding of `test` is used, whose SHA256 hash is hex encoded `9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08`.

*Remark 1:* If a *double* SHA256 hashing is used as noted in the comment, the SHA256 hash of `test` is to be used as test message instead of `test`. Apart from that the further processing is the same.

The Python and Go code are currently incompatible because they differ in signing and signature format:

- With regard to signing: In the Python code, the hashed message is passed. This is correct because `sign_digest()` does not hash the message (see [here](https://github.com/tlsfuzzer/python-ecdsa/blob/master/src/ecdsa/keys.py#L1590)), and thus the hashed message is signed.
  In contrast, `sign()` in the Go code hashes the message (see [here](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/blob/master/crypto/secp256k1/secp256k1.go#L194)), so the message *itself* must be passed for the processing to be functionally identical to the Python code.
- With regard to the signature format: the Python code uses the ASN.1/DER format, while the Go code uses the IEEE P1363 format.
  Therefore, a conversion from IEEE P1363 to ASN.1/DER must be performed in the Go code:

With this, the fixed Go code is:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"

    "math/big"

    "github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/crypto/hd"
    "github.com/cosmos/go-bip39"
    "github.com/tendermint/tendermint/crypto/secp256k1"

    //"github.com/btcsuite/btcd/btcec"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte/asn1"
)

func main() {

    //
    // Derive private and public key (this part works)
    //
    seed := bip39.NewSeed("blast about old claw current first paste risk involve victory edit current", "")
    fmt.Println("Seed: ", hex.EncodeToString(seed)) // Seed:  dd5ffa7088c0fa4c665085bca7096a61e42ba92e7243a8ad7fbc6975a4aeea1845c6b668ebacd024fd2ca215c6cd510be7a9815528016af3a5e6f47d1cca30dd

    master, ch := hd.ComputeMastersFromSeed(seed)
    path := "m/44'/1022'/0'/0/0'"
    priv, _ := hd.DerivePrivateKeyForPath(master, ch, path)
    fmt.Println("Derivation Path: ", path)                 // Derivation Path:  m/44'/1022'/0'/0/0'
    fmt.Println("Private Key: ", hex.EncodeToString(priv)) // Private Key:  33f34dad4bc0ce9dc320863509aed43cab33a93a29752779ae0df6dbbea33e56

    var privKey = secp256k1.PrivKey(priv)
    pubKey := privKey.PubKey()
    fmt.Println("Public Key: ", hex.EncodeToString(pubKey.Bytes())) // Public Key:  026557fe37d5cab1cc8edf474f4baff67dbb2305f1764e42d31b09f83296f5de2b

    //
    // Sign (this part needs to be fixed)
    //
    data := "test"

    signature, _ := privKey.Sign([]byte(data))
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(signature))

    rVal := new(big.Int)
    rVal.SetBytes(signature[0:32])
    sVal := new(big.Int)
    sVal.SetBytes(signature[32:64])
    var b cryptobyte.Builder
    b.AddASN1(asn1.SEQUENCE, func(b *cryptobyte.Builder) {
        b.AddASN1BigInt(rVal)
        b.AddASN1BigInt(sVal)
    })
    signatureDER, _ := b.Bytes()
    fmt.Println("Signature, DER: ", hex.EncodeToString(signatureDER))

    /*
        hash, _ := hex.DecodeString("9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08")

        // Sign without hashing
        privateKey, _ := btcec.PrivKeyFromBytes(btcec.S256(), priv)
        signature, _ := privateKey.Sign(hash[:])

        // Convert to ASN1/DER
        rVal := new(big.Int)
        rVal.SetBytes(signature.R.Bytes())
        sVal := new(big.Int)
        sVal.SetBytes(signature.S.Bytes())
        var b cryptobyte.Builder
        b.AddASN1(asn1.SEQUENCE, func(b *cryptobyte.Builder) {
            b.AddASN1BigInt(rVal)
            b.AddASN1BigInt(sVal)
        })
        signatureDER, _ := b.Bytes()
        fmt.Println("Signature, DER: ", hex.EncodeToString(signatureDER))
    */
}
```

*Remark 2:* If the original message is not available in the Go code, but only the hash, a function that does not hash is needed for signing.
The tendermint/crypto/secp256k1 package does not support this, but tendermint/crypto/secp256k1 uses internally btcsuite/btcd/btcec which does.
This is implemented in the commented-out code.

The output is:

```
Seed:  dd5ffa7088c0fa4c665085bca7096a61e42ba92e7243a8ad7fbc6975a4aeea1845c6b668ebacd024fd2ca215c6cd510be7a9815528016af3a5e6f47d1cca30dd
Derivation Path:  m/44'/1022'/0'/0/0'
Private Key:  33f34dad4bc0ce9dc320863509aed43cab33a93a29752779ae0df6dbbea33e56
Public Key:  026557fe37d5cab1cc8edf474f4baff67dbb2305f1764e42d31b09f83296f5de2b
57624717f71fae8b5917cde0f82dfe6c2e2104183ba01c6a1c9f0a8e66d3303e5035b52876d833522aace232c1d231b3aeeff303cf02d1677a240102365ce71b
Signature, DER:  3044022057624717f71fae8b5917cde0f82dfe6c2e2104183ba01c6a1c9f0a8e66d3303e02205035b52876d833522aace232c1d231b3aeeff303cf02d1677a240102365ce71b
```

---

**Test:**

Since the Python code generates a non-deterministic signature, verification by comparing the signatures is not possible.
Instead, a possible test is to check the signatures of both codes with the *same* verification code.
For this purpose, in the method `sign()` of the Python code the lines

```py
return signing_key.sign_digest(  # type: ignore
    digest=bytearray.fromhex(data),
    sigencode=sigencode_der
).hex()
```

can be replaced by

```py
from ecdsa.util import sigdecode_der 
signature = signing_key.sign_digest(  # from Python Code
    digest=bytearray.fromhex(data),
    sigencode=sigencode_der
)
#signature = bytes.fromhex('3044022057624717f71fae8b5917cde0f82dfe6c2e2104183ba01c6a1c9f0a8e66d3303e02205035b52876d833522aace232c1d231b3aeeff303cf02d1677a240102365ce71b') # from Go code    
verifying_key = signing_key.verifying_key
verified = verifying_key.verify_digest(signature, digest=bytearray.fromhex(data), sigdecode=sigdecode_der)
print(verified)
return signature.hex()
```

The test shows that both, the Python and Go code signatures are successfully verified, proving that the signature generated with the Go code is valid.

---

*Remark 3:* The Python code generates a non-deterministic signature, i.e. the signature is different even with identical input data.
In contrast, the Go code generates a deterministic signature, i.e. the signature is the same for identical input data (see [here](https://github.com/decred/dcrd/blob/master/dcrec/secp256k1/ecdsa/signature.go#L665)).

If the Go code should also generate a non-deterministic signature, other libraries must be used on the Go side (but this might not actually be necessary, since the non-deterministic and the deterministic variant are established algorithms and generate valid signatures in accordance with the above test).

Comment: Thanks alot for the solution , much appreciated , have a good day :)